# Windows Server takes 5 minutes to log in via Remote Desktop? Stand alone server

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, login

It's a Dell PE 2900 with Windows Server 2003 standard 64 bit, all windows updates applied.

CPU and Network are always under ten percent.  Only Helios (file sharing) and SQL Server 2005 running on it.  Eight 250 gig Sata hard drives with a Perc 6 controller, raid 5, one partition and it's read only to users.

Any ideas?

Comment: how fast is the connection once it's established, is it slow or normal?

Comment: The connection is fast because I can take windows and move them around quickly.  But, clicking on the start menu for example takes about 10 seconds to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Virtual Memory was configured on a print spool drive.  I moved the swap file to a separate physical disk and everything started working well.